# material ui V5 change pointer when MuiButton is disabled

Tags: material-ui, styling

Trying to change the cursor and startIcon when a button is disabled, in the theme to prevent from repeating for each button, but can not find the solution.
`&:hover` is not taking into account, and can not find the `startIcon` property in override.

Any help would be appreciated.
Running MUI V5.0.6

```js
    const theme = createTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: white,
        },
        secondary: {
          main: "#19857b",
        },
        error: {
          main: red.A400,
        },
      },
      components: {
        MuiButton: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              backgroundColor: blue[200],
              "&.Mui-disabled": {
                backgroundColor: "#ef9a9a",
              },
              "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: blue[400],
              },
    
              "&.Mui-disabled:hover": {
                cursor: "not-allowed", <-- has no effect, the cursor is still a pointer
                startIcon <-- property doesn't exists
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mui's `Button` component have `pointer-events: none;` set when disabled.

See: [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/5fa30df9336fc351e4dbf35dad9fb4bccc3b3f34/packages/mui-material/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L59-L62)

You can override this:

```js
MuiButton: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      "&.Mui-disabled": {
        pointerEvents: "unset", // allow :hover styles to be triggered
        cursor: "not-allowed", // and custom cursor can be defined without :hover state
        backgroundColor: "#ef9a9a"
      },
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "green"
      }
    },
    // styles applied when `startIcon` prop is set
    startIcon: {
      // styles applied to the icon when disabled
      ".Mui-disabled &": {
        color: "red"
      },
      color: "yellow"
    }
  }
}
```

See the [codesandbox i've made](https://codesandbox.io/s/customstyles-material-demo-forked-u3rxf?file=/demo.js) for a working example.

Comment: brilliant. !! Thks 
Still search how to change startIcon color when button disabled.

Comment: i've updated the example and the codesandbox to show how

Comment: tried this but with no luck ```` startIcon: {
          color: "green",
          "&.Mui-disabled": {
            color: "red",
          },
        },```

Comment: thks. So weird the & is at the end and not at the begging

Comment: It's `".Mui-disabled &"` not `"&.Mui-disabled"`, the position of '&' matter

Comment: gi tit thks a lot

Comment: if my answer resolved your issue, please mark it as such :)